# to print address space of a process in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

How do I print an address space of a process by taking the process' PID?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's `/proc/$PID/maps` but I don't know if that's relevant to what you're trying to get at or not.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with

```
cat /proc/<number_of_pid>/maps
```